# Iterate process in R using range of vectors derived from matrix

Tags: r, loops, vector, matrix, iteration

I must first apologize as I have no programming background, so please forgive me if this question is overly simplistic or if it has been addressed repeatedly. I would be very willing to help clarify my issue if it is not clear from my explanation.

I have two sets of data matrices. "A":

```
    [Ac1] [Ac2] ... [Ac500]
[Ac1]  25   30 ...   15
[Ar2]  7    54 ...   41
... 
[cr25000]
```

and

"B" which is similar in the number of columns, but not the number of rows

```
    [Bc1] [Bc2] ... [Bc500]
[Br1]  25  30 ...    15
[Br2]  7   54 ...    41
... 
[Br20000]
```

I'm running an module ("npSeq") in R that uses the matrix A consistently as an input value, a horizontal vector that includes all of the values from a row in matrix B, ex [1]. The module returns a separate list of values. I will need to run the analysis independently for all of the rows in matrix B saving all of the returned lists which I will then need to combine.

However I would like to know if there is a way to automate the process so that the module runs using a vector derived from row [Br1], saves the returned list, and then runs the process again using the vector derived from row [Br2]. Repeating the process until [Br20000].

Again I'm sorry that this is worded so poorly. I wish I understood enough of the terminology to state my problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to loop over `B`'s row indices:

```
result.list <- lapply(1:nrow(B), function(i) npSeq(A, B[i, ]))
```

Note that this is not going to be much (any?) faster than using a `for` loop. It is just a short and clean equivalent. 20,000 iterations does sound like a lot so it may take a while depending on how slow the function is.